# PHP file upload to linux cPanel shows success but file is nowhere to be found

Tags: php, linux, file-upload, cpanel

This is my first post here to stackoverflow. I searched for other solutions to this problem on this site but was unable to find any solution. I even had an extensive session with GoDaddy support that was unsuccessful.

Here is my code, which is slighty modified from the PHP reference:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
// In PHP versions earlier than 4.1.0, $HTTP_POST_FILES should be used instead
// of $_FILES.

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$tmpfile = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}

echo 'File name: '.$uploadfile."\r\n";
echo 'Temp file: '.$tmpfile."\r\n\r\n";
echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";
}
}
?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#" method="POST">
    <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
    <!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array -->
    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The output when I upload a file is this:

```
Warning:  move_uploaded_file(uploads/Bender.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/nflaum/public_html/_working/file_upload.php on line 15



Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpWmeSDx' to 'uploads/Bender.jpg' in /home/nflaum/public_html/_working/file_upload.php on line 15

Possible file upload attack! File name: uploads/Bender.jpg Temp file: /tmp/phpWmeSDx

Here is some more debugging info:Array (
    [userfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => Bender.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpWmeSDx
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 91463
        )

)
```

Here are things I have already tried:

1. Created my own php.ini file and tried every combination of upload_tmp_dir imaginable (verifying with phpinfo), both on my own and with a GoDaddy rep. Verified file_uploads is on and all settings are ok.
2. Verified that the folders had 777 permissions for every combination tried.
3. Tried renaming .htaccess in case some routing configuration was causing an issue.
4. Connected to SSH and checked the root /tmp folder to see if it was there (GoDaddy sets home folder to /home/)

None of it resolved the issue. It looks like PHP thinks the file is being uploaded correctly, yet it's nowhere to be found. I'm hoping one of the geniuses on this forum is able to help me see something I've missed.

Comment: Couple of quick thoughts, Have you tried using an absolute path for the uploaded file? move_uploaded_file() is also subject to open_basedir and safe_mode restrictions.

Comment: I'm on cPanel which is on a shared host through my provider, but I have tried using /home/nflaum/<dir> which is what my provider assigns to me. That's s absolute as I know how to get. Also, shouldn't the tmp file exist before move_uploaded_file() is ever executed? It's my understanding that there should be a tmp file located on the server in the upload_tmp_dir folder. Without this tmp file, the move_uploaded_file() will always fail because there's no file to move.

Answer (score 0):

I think the path is not correct from the script current position. Did you check that? Is the folder "uploads" in the same directory of the file_upload.php script?

Comment: It was at the time I tested it. Since then I have focused on cleaning up my site/directory structure a bit and things may have changed. But even given that, shouldn't the tmp file still exist in the tmp directory? Or is tmp like some spot in memory and doesn't represent an actual file?

Comment: Maybe the problem is not the temp folder but the "upload" one. Maybe your path to the "uploads" folder is wrong.